# How to pass a variable as a command line argument in iPython?

Tags: python, ipython

For example, I have a Python module and a iPython module,

cmd.py

```
import sys
print sys.argv
```

test.ipynb

```
for i in range(5):
   %run cmd.py i
```

When I run test.ipynb, it just print ['cmd.py', 'i'] multiple times. How can I pass the value of i instead of 'i' as a command line argument?

Comment: have you tried `%run cmd.py $i` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the shell mode interprets everything literally (else `cmd.py` would be evaluated as well). I would just do:

```
for i in range(5):
   %run cmd.py $i
```

from http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/reference.html

> IPython also allows you to expand the value of python variables when making system calls. Wrap variables or expressions in {braces}:
>
> For simple cases, you can alternatively prepend $ to a variable name

Comment: I must admin I spent at least 15 minutes in the documentation to find the information. Wasn't the most accessible piece of information :)